# ACCESS_MASK : bits in Value

Tags: c++

Very first beginner question .-)

The MSDN documentation [ACCESS_MASK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374892%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374892%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) show the ACCESS_MASK data Type:

Example_code:

```
#define DELETE                           (0x00010000L) //in Winnt.h

ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE* ace;

...
mask = ((ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE*)ace)->Mask

..
if (DELETE & ace->Mask) {
            std::wcout << " Delete: " << **ace->Mask** << "\n";
        }
```

... give me the output:

```
"Delete: **197055**"
```

What is the meaning of "0 15 Bits" ?
How can I print the "16 to 23" Bit?

Thanks for a 'visual' explanation.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You are printing the 16 to 23 bits. Do you mean print the 16 to 23 bits **only**?

Comment: And I don't understand what you don't understand about the 0 to 15 bits. The page you linked to gives a reasonable explanation of their meaning.

Comment: So maybe you don't understand the whole concept of a *bit field*, is that the issue here? Integers can be thought of as short vectors of bits, so there's a bit 0, a bit 1, a bit 2 etc. and a range of those bits like bit 0 to bit 15, is called a bit field.

Comment: The output show's the  ace-Mask  "0 to 31" Bit (I think) , but how can I output the 16 to 23 Bit of the ace->Mask? The DELETE is defined as 0x00010000 -> How can I find this Value in the output?

Comment: OK, that would be `(ace->Mask&DELETE)`, bits 16 to 23 would be `(ace->Mask&0x00FF0000)`, bits 0 to 15 would be `(ace->Mask&0x0000FFFF)`

Comment: But the value of `DELETE` is `0x00010000` as you've already said.

Comment: Or maybe you are asking how to print in hexadecimal? That would be `std::wcout << " Delete: " << hex << ace->Mask << "\n"`

Comment: Hi john, thanks a lot for your patience. If i print ace->Mask&Delete the output is " Delete: 65536 "

Comment: oh, I got it! If I print  <<Hex << (ace->Mask&DELETE) thje output is "Delete: 10000"  Thank for your support!